# SelectPdf File Access

Tags: iis, selectpdf

I am using SelectPdf to convert an HTML document to PDF.
The document has images in it and I use baseUrl in the conversion when calling ConvertHtmlString().

This all works fine when running under Visual Studio / localhost.

However, in the production environment, while the PDF is still generated from the HTML, the images are absent from the PDF.
I deploy to a Windows Server EC2 instance.

- I have checked the HTML file is on the server.
- I have checked the images are on the server.
- I checked the file permissions for the images.  Adminstrators, Users, IIS_USRS all have read access.

I assume since it works on my local computer but not EC2, that there must be a permissions issue, but not sure where else to look.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set permissions for Everyone to see if it works. If that will work, it's a permissions issue. If it does not work, it's something else. You could try to insert 1-2 seconds conversion delay to allow the images to load.